# Weird message getting with serialization and c#

Tags: c#, serialization, tcp, client-server

I tried to send it from one client to another, and the source, destination and the data receive fine, but the string and the double become null. This is the code of the `TcpObject`:

```
[Serializable]
public class TcpObject
{
    public Command Command { set; get; }
    public Object Data { set; get; }
    public int Source { set; get; }
    public int Destination { set; get; }
    public string IDString { set; get; }
    public double exactTime { set; get; }

    public TcpObject()
    {
       Command = Command.Null;
       Data = null;
    }
```

This is where I send the data:

```
TcpObject tcpObject = new TcpObject();
tcpObject.Command = Command.Msg;
tcpObject.Source = 1;
tcpObject.Destination = 2;
byte[] junkMsg = new byte[1000];
tcpObject.Data = junkMsg;
tcpObject.IDString = randomString();
tcpObject.exactTime = exactTime.ExactTime();
WorkClient.Send(tcpObject);
hread.Sleep(20);
```

And this is where I receive:

```
public void Listen()
{
   try
   {
      while (Connected)
      {
         TcpObject tcpObject = new TcpObject();
         IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
         tcpObject = (TcpObject)formatter.Deserialize(ServerSocket);

         MessageBox.Show(tcpObject.IDString);
         //TcpObject succeedTcpObject = new TcpObject();
         //get the remainder of the time that the message got send and when the message got accepted.
      }
   }
      catch (Exception) { }
}
```

This is the send function:

```
public static void Send(TcpObject tcpObject) 
{
   try
   {
      IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
      formatter.Serialize(ServerSocket, tcpObject);
   }
   catch (Exception) { }
}
```

The MessageBox that pops up is empty. I checked before I sent the msg and the string was present.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you send garbage that is never initialized:

```
byte[] junkMsg = new byte[1000];
tcpObject.Data = junkMsg;
--SNIP--
WorkClient.Send(tcpObject);
```

Comment: how come it is never initialized if i used the new keyword? and by the way what does it has to do with IDString and exactTime?

Comment: The `new` keyword just allocates the data on the heap. To initialize, say the first byte, you would need to do `junkMsg[0] = `. The `new` keyword just initializes the data to its `default(x)` value, which in this case is `0`.

Comment: It doesn't have to do with them, that's why I snipped them.

Comment: But my problem is with IDString and exactTime, I can edit the Data with the bytes array later.

Comment: You state that you get garbage. The only logical place your "error" would be coming from is here.

Comment: I tried to do the next thing: public TcpObject() { Command = Command.Null; Data = null; IDString = "PleaseWork"; } and when I start debugging it is showing me "PleaseWork" in the MessageBox, but still dont work when I want to assign it from outside.